# Replace the child node in c#

Tags: asp.net, string, c#-4.0

I have a string HTML code like

```
 <table id='topInfoBar' style=" width: 100%;" cellspacing='0' border='0'>
 <Tr>
 <td id='lockOrder' clientidmode='static'  style="text-align:Right;color:black;font-weight:bold">  
 <img src='.../images/locked.gif' alt='This order is locked' title='This order is locked!' />
 </td>
 </Tr>
 </table>
```

I want to check if id **'lockOrder'** exists in the string and if yes, want to replace img node i.e

`<img src='.../images/locked.gif' alt='This order is locked' title='This order is locked!' />`

with

```
 <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x cursorpointer"  title="This order is locked"></i>
```

want to do it in c#.

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you have a problem with straight string manipulation, eg `myHtmlString.Contains("lockOrder")` and `myHtmlString.Replace(oneImgLine,anotherImgLine)` ? It's not the most efficient way but it should work

Comment: Are you asking how to show/hide an element in an ASP.NET page or how to replace text in an HTML string? Your question doesn't contain anything related to ASP.NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is string having HTML code and want to manipulate from code behind

Answer (score 1):

Use property `Visible` and change it in if

HTML

```
<table id='topInfoBar' style="width: 100%;" cellspacing='0' border='0'>
    <Tr>
        <td id='lockOrder' clientidmode='static' style="text-align: Right; color: black; font-weight: bold">
            <img src='.../images/locked.gif' alt='This order is locked' title='This order is locked!' runat="server" id="img"/>
            <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x cursorpointer" title="This order is locked" runat="server" id="i" Visible="False"></i>

        </td>
    </Tr>
</table>
```

CodeBehind C#

```
            if (true)
            {
                img.Visible = false;
                i.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: I don't think this is an ASP.NET question. Besides, using this code-behind would only work in webforms